# Does the following javascript code have undefined behavior?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, undefined-behavior, es6-promise

```js
var resolve;

var head = { next: new Promise( r => resolve = r ) };

function addData(d) {
    resolve({
       data: d,
       next: new Promise(r => resolve = r)
    });
}
```

I wrote the above code to achieve something similar to linked-list, while the data in the list is loaded asynchronously.

The head of this "linked-list" is `head`. Each node in the list has two fields, `.data` and `.next`, like a normal linked list. `.next` is a promise which will resolve to the next node in the list.

Everytime `addData(...)` is called, the `.next` field of current last node in the list will resolve to a new node and thus becoming the new last node.

I have verified the functionality of the above code in Node.js and it works as expected. Here is the code I use to verify the behavior:

```js
var resolve;
var head = { next: new Promise( r => resolve = r ) };
function addData(d) { resolve({ data: d, next: new Promise(r => resolve = r) }); }

async function verify() {
    while(true) {
        head = await head.next;
        console.log(head.data);
    }
}

verify();
addData(1); // outputs: 1
addData(2); // outputs: 2
addData(3); // outputs: 3
```

However, I'm not sure if there's any potential issue (memory, efficiency) with this structure. Also, I'm particularly worried about this line:

`resolve({data: d, next: new Promise(r => resolve = r})`

where resolve is called and assigned at the same time. Which should happen first, assignment or function name resolution? Is this an undefined behavior?

Thank you!

Comment: Whether it works or not, it sure is obtuse (hard to read and understand the point of the code).

Comment: @jfriend00 He'd only retain the whole chain if he kept a reference to the initial head, which he doesn't do. Of course, it's easy to get wrong…

Comment: @Bergi - I had already deleted that comment because I've concluded this is too hard to understand what is going on (bad code in my opinion for that reason).  But, the OP did say "like a linked list", but I guess it isn't really a linked list at all.  I guess it's just a higher scoped cache of the previous promise.  Isn't there a much, much better way to do this that isn't so obtuse and doesn't use the higher scoped `resolve` variable?

Comment: @jfriend00 It looks like a confusing implementation of a stream or observable collection.

Comment: @jfriend00 The difference to a simple cache is that it can hold multiple promises in the chain. Reading and writing could happen at different speeds. I'd call it an *asynchronous queue* though (and name the methods accordingly, and close over the free variables), but apart from that the implementation is pretty standard.

Comment: @JLRishe Thank you for the comment! I admit that the code is hard to understand. If I have to implement this "linked-list"-ish structure, is there any better/elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Which should happen first, assignment or function name resolution?

Function name resolution happens before the evaluation of the arguments (the object literal, which includes the `Promise` constructor call, which in turn invokes the callback, which includes the assignment).

> Is this an undefined behavior?

No. But a code smell.

> Is there any better/more elegant way to do this?

Yes. It depends mostly on how the data structure is generated. If you are using a functional approach, I'd recommend a recursive function:

```
function getStream(i) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, 100);
    }).then(() => ({
        data: i,
        next: getStream(i+1)
    }));
}
(async function() {
    for (var data, next, head = getStream(1); {data, next} = await head; head = next) {
        console.log(data);
    }
}());
```

If you use an imperative approach where somebody else produces the data, I'd call the list an *asynchronous queue* and put in an appropriate structure, but your `addData` code is fine (except for the confusion about `resolve` which you can manage with an extra variable).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! If I have to implement this "linked-list"-ish structure, is there any better/elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

As Bergi points out, this is not undefined behavior, but there are ways to implement this that aren't quite as confusing.

For example, you could write the `addData` function so that it doesn't assign the `resolve` function and call it in the same statement:

```
function addData(d) { 
    let newResolve;

    resolve({ data: d, next: new Promise(r => newResolve = r) }); 

    resolve = newResolve;
}
```

It looks like you might be using a very roundabout approach to creating a stream or observable collection, in which case, you might just be better off using an existing implementation of one of those.

Comment: How is storing a deferred better than storing a `resolve` function?

Comment: @Bergi It seems a bit clearer to me, but fair point. I've changed my answer to avoid the confusing line that calls and assigns `resolve` in the same statement.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and suggestions! The application is really complicate to explain in a few words. I'll try to find some existing implementation that fits the requirement....